# WKWebView evaluateJavaScript completionHandler not called in iOS 11

Tags: wkwebview, ios11

```
let eval = "getTarget('\(url.absoluteString)')"
webView.evaluateJavaScript(eval, 
completionHandler: {(response, error) in
})
```

completionhandler does not get called in iOS 11 at all. Works fine on iOS 10.

Anybody workaround for this? 
OR
Is there an alternative for evaluateJavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Xamarin (with iOS 11).
I fixed this with `InvokeOnMainThread`.
For example:

```
InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
      webView.EvaluateJavaScript($"example('{text}')", (response, error) => {}
}
```

Maybe you will find similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 11 requires evaluateJavaScript be called on the main thread. So surround your call with DispatchQueue.main.async{} if you are not calling it from the main thread.